# Make simultaneous web requests in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Could someone point me to snippet for making parallel web-requests? I need to make 6 web requests and concatenate the HTML result.

Is there a quick way to accomplish this or do i have to go the threading way?

Thank you.

Comment: How would you do it other than threads? If there's a framework that does it, it's going to use threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with [`Callable<InputStream>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Kickoff example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
Future<InputStream> response1 = executor.submit(new Request("http://google.com"));
Future<InputStream> response2 = executor.submit(new Request("http://stackoverflow.com"));
// ...
ByteArrayOutputStream totalResponse = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
copyAndCloseInput(response1.get(), totalResponse);
copyAndCloseInput(response2.get(), totalResponse);
// ...
executor.shutdown();
```

with

```
public class Request implements Callable<InputStream> {

    private String url;

    public Request(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream call() throws Exception {
        return new URL(url).openStream();
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial: Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend learning about [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). It allows you to run tasks simultaneously and would work well for the scenario you describe.